# How to add sub collection to a document adding data in Firestore?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

How to add a sub collection to a document adding data using Java?
I want to add like this: 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqa94.png)

I tried like this but didn't work: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SAfB.png)

```
Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(Long.toString(id)).add({name: this.name}).collection("lands").document();

ApiFuture<WriteResult> result = docRef.set(docRef);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Right now, you're just linking to two of the same image of a database structure.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed

Comment: I think I wasn't clear before - you should copy and paste the relevant code into the question rather than posting screenshots of code.  It will be easier to read and copy back into an answer if needed.

Comment: You are right! Thank You!

Comment: You're going to get all kinds of compile errors on that.  It's not clear to me at all what you're hoping to accomplish.